# Locking a document with firebase rules

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have this set of rules in firestore

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
  
    match /{document} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if isTrustworthy();
    }
    match /stores/{storeId}{
      match /{document} {
        allow read: if true;
        allow write: if isTrustworthy();
      }
      match /departures/{departureId} {
        allow read: if true;
        allow write: if !(resource.data.locked);
      }  
    }
        
    function isTrustworthy(){
      return isSignedIn() && emailVerified();
    }
    
    function isSignedIn() {
      return request.auth != null;
    }
    function emailVerified() {
      return request.auth.token.email_verified;
    }
  }
}
```

but I get an error when setting, updating or deleting in the departures path.

eg.

```
this.afs.collection('stores').doc(this.auth.store)
   .collection('departures')
   .doc(element.shipping.trackingNumber.toString())
   .set({"test":true})
```

the document is not existent, but it won't work neither if the document exist, independent of the parameter "locked"
I got the following error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]: Missing or insufficient permissions.
>
> FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.

What I need is that if the document has a parameter "locked" set to true, it cannot be deleted, updated, nor set with {merge:true} option.

any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues with your rule and code:

1. On `create`, `resource.data` does not exist
2. On `update` or `delete`, it could be that the field `locked` does not exist
3. When you use `set` to create or update a document in Firestore, you have to add the options `{merge: true}`, to update the document instead of overwriting it in case it already exists.

Try this instead:

- Code:

  ```
  this.afs.collection('stores').doc(this.auth.store)
    .collection('departures')
    .doc(element.shipping.trackingNumber.toString())
    .set({"test":true}, {merge: true})
  ```
- Rules:

  ```
  match /departures/{departureId} {
    allow read: if true;
    allow create: if true;
    allow update, delete: if !resource.data.get("locked", false);
  }
  ```

Answer (score -1):

I add a set of functions to my rules to make writing rules like this easier:

```
    function existing() {
        return resource.data;
    }
    function resulting() {
        return request.resource.data;
    }
    function matchField(fieldName) {
        return existing()[fieldName] == resulting()[fieldName];
    }
```

`resource` refers to the document being accessed, and `request.resource` refers to the new data for the document.  With these you can refer to values on the existing or incoming document.

The `matchField` is useful in combination with various claims/Roles protect *parts* of the document(s) from being changed.

In your case you can check the status of a specific field "`locked`", for example some form of:

```
match /whatever/points/to/the/doc {
  allow write: if !existing().locked
}
```

(I use a couple dozen such functions MOSTLY to make my rules almost look like text)

Comment: Note these functions do NOT use any sort of "get" - the request and resource structures are already part of the information available to the rules.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions, but this does not resolve the issue since existing() is the same as resource.data and setting to this path get blocked unless i put allow write;